# flex 3 screenshot of the scene

Tags: flex3, screenshot

i want to snapshot of the flex scene and save it as a image. It likes printscreen button and paste it to paint and save

there will a button save it to desktop and when pressed it, flex will save the screenshot of scene to the desktop, i searched on the net but couldn't find a working code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a way to do it, but it requires some serverside work.  Basically the data is sent to the server and the server saves it.

What you would probably want to do since you want the user to have the screenshot is create the files on the server then have it open a web page where they can download and save it.

more information is here http://www.boyzoid.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/9/17/Doing-screenshots-in-Flex-and-sending-them-to-ColdFusion

Comment: i want to user to save the picture to local and use that picture in an other module. Because of this, it should save to user machine